Org-mode special block collision with structure template
In org-mode I can insert a special block using C-c C-, RET, for example when I want to insert a 'theorem' environment for a LaTeX export, I can write C-c C-, RET theorem which inserts a block like
#+begin_theorem
#+end_theorem

and if I then export to a LaTeX file using C-c C-e l l there will be a corresponding LaTeX theorem environment
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

However if I insert an 'example' environment
#+begin_example
#+end_example

Then this will not export to the LaTeX 'example' environment, but to the LaTeX 'verbatim' environment
\begin{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}

because it will collide with org-mode's 'example' structure template.
One possible workaround is to rename the LaTeX 'example' environment so that it will not collide, for example to 'exampple'.
But as I do not need the built-in org-mode 'example' environment I was wondering if it would be possible to remove the built-in environment and default to a LaTeX special block instead.

A quick workaround is to write the latex commands directly in org-mode and associate a shortcut to it, via a snippet for instance. For instance, typing ex and hitting tab could produce \begin{example} ... \end{example} directly in org-mode.

There are various solutions, depending on where along the spectrum you fall.
Method 1: Modify each example block
You can modify each example block as follows:

#+attr_latex: :environment example
#+begin_example
foo
#+end_example

That puts the burden on the end user (i.e. you in your end-user role), but does not require any modification to the code, although you might consider modifying the structure template code to always add the attribute to the example block. But if you just have a file where you want to do that, typing it in the first time and cutting-and-pasting for every other example block is the way I would go.
Method 2: Modify the LaTeX exporter
The LaTeX exporter (actually every exporter) relies on a data structure that maps syntactic elements to transcoding functions. The data structure is constructed by the function org-export-define-backend. Its second argument is an alist of pairs of the form (<syntax element> . <transcoding function>), e.g. (example-block . org-element-example-block). So you can modify the transcoding function to do what you want:
(defun org-latex-example-block (example-block _contents info)
  "Transcode an EXAMPLE-BLOCK element from Org to LaTeX.
CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist holding contextual
information."
  (when (org-string-nw-p (org-element-property :value example-block))
    (let ((environment (or (org-export-read-attribute
                :attr_latex example-block :environment)
               "example")))     ; <-- change the default from "verbatim" to "example"
      (org-latex--wrap-label
       example-block
       (format "\\begin{%s}\n%s\\end{%s}"
           environment
           (org-export-format-code-default example-block info)
           environment)
       info))))

This is just a copy of the original function, with the only change being to change the default environment from verbatim to example - see the marked line above. You add that to your init file inside a (with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex ...) form and you are done: your function will override the identically-named function defined in ox-latex:
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
    (defun org-latex-example-block (example-block _contents info)
       ...
     ))

The disadvantage here is that if you want to use the original, you'll have to comment out or delete the redefinition and restart Emacs (or navigate to the original function definition and evaluate it again; or reload ox-latex). But you can't have both definitions active at the same time. From what you say, that wouldn't be much of a problem for you.
The other disadvantage is that you are really forking the "official" Org mode code, so it's conceivable that a change in that code in the future will break your workaround. But I don't think there is much chance that that will happen in this case.
Method 3: Define a derived exporter backend
You can easily define your own exporter backend, particularly in the case when it is mostly identical to an already existing one and just making one or two modifications: in that case, you can define your own derived backend, inheriting from the existing one.
You can do that with org-export-derived-backend. You can see an instance of such a derived backend in this Emacs SE answer, so I'm going to refer you to that instead of rehashing that solution here. In this case, you'd have to reimplement org-latex-example-block as above, instead of org-latex-template as is done in the other answer, but I hope the steps will be clear.
The advantage here is that you can export using either the original latex backend or your derived one: the two coexist peacefully. The disadvantage is that in addition to the (simple) changes, you also have to provide some boilerplate code in order to hook the new backend into the existing machinery (e.g. the export dispatcher you get when you press C-c C-e).
